# How can we get automatic related, up-sell & cross-sell products in magento 1.9 without any extension?

Tags: related-products, cross-sells, up-sells, magento1.9.2.3

I want to display related, up-sell & cross-sell products generated automatically without using any extension?

Comment: Did you find any free stuff?

Comment: No, didn't get.

Answer (score 0):

I think Below Link Shuold be Use for you:
 http://stuntcoders.com/magento-tutorials/magento-products/adding-related-products/

Comment: It is manual process, in your given url,  but my question for automatic generate related, cross-sell & up-sell products without any extension.